# Shorten call to Rails.application.secrets for readability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, readability

I know this is a bit of a nitpick, but this has been staring me in the face all day as I'm trying to move over to using the new[ish] `config/secrets.yml` file. It's just making my code ugly. I'm aware that moving to something less standard could be a problem if it comes to someone trying to understand my project... but this project is pretty private and i'm the only one working on it.

It seems that it's an instance of `ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions` so I can't seem to `alias` it.

How could I alias something like `SECRET` to `Rails.application.secrets` so that I could call `SECRET.some_key` to get a return value?

I'm looking for a solution that:

- Has minimal performance impacts
- Has minimal to zero security impacts

Thanks a zillion!

Comment: Why not just assign `Rails.application.secrets` to `SECRET` or `@secret` somewhere. `SECRET = Rails.application.secrets` works for me in the console; I can then access `SECRET.secret_key_base` etc.

Comment: Wow! I really didn't think it would be that simple. I'd just like to add that I just put it in my `config/application.rb` file for access all over my project. 
If you don't mind submitting that as an answer, I would happily mark your answer correct. Though, I would like to hear from anyone else if there are potential security implications I'm not thinking of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just assign `Rails.application.secrets` to `SECRET` or `@secret` somewhere?

```
SECRET = Rails.application.secrets
```

works for me in the console; I can then access `SECRET.secret_key_base` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you don't like the aesthetics of a `SECRET` constant:

```
module Secret
  def self.for
    Rails.application.secrets
  end
end
```

Will shorten

```
Rails.application.secrets.my_value
```

to:

```
Secret.for.my_value
```